# Description on the homepage could be updated

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, front-page

If you are not logged in and visit the homepage of Stack Overflow it says:
[image]

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and
>   enthusiast programmers. It's 100% free, no registration required.

However, if you do try to ask a question logged out you are sent to the login page and are told to either log in or sign up. So the sentence "It's 100% free, no registration required." is only partly true and could be updated . I know on some of the stack exchange sites you can ask a question as a guest.

Comment: [Clarify the “No registration required” message](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120707/clarify-the-no-registration-required-message)

Comment: If that Meta.SE Question was here on Meta.SO, I'd vote to close as duplicate.  Theoretically it could be migrated here, as the issue is specific enough to StackOverflow (most SE community sites allow Questions by unregistered users).

Comment: @hardmath But there *are* other sites out there that require registration. Ask Ubuntu, Programmers SE, Physics SE, and even Meta SE all require registration. There are more, but I don't know the exact list of all of them off the top of my head.

Comment: @animuson: Shame on me for not knowing (and thanks for the info).  Maybe the fact that I can offer a bonus on Meta.SE (but not here) will actually be useful in raising awareness/promoting action.

Comment: Done:  Bounty posted on the Meta.SE version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You managed to convince JNat, and he convinced the rest of us. The message now ends with, "It's 100% free."

Answer (score -15):

I would suggest to update the description to: 
"Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional programmers only."

so you can ensure no begginer (greenie) will bother you with some silly questions.

this is my personal impression after hanging here for couple of days.

Comment: People don't read anything ever, including our handy guides on things like "how to ask a good question" or "what questions are off-topic".

Comment: Everybody's a beginner at something.

Comment: Exactly, when one asks a question, it happens because he/she doesn't know. Then get critisized for not knowing... It is a nonsense for me.